# How do I set global scale dimensions for 3d printing 1:1?

Tags: transforms, 3d-printing, dimensions, screw-modifier

I try to prototype in Blender for later exporting it into STL files. I tried the [Bolt Factory](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_mesh/boltfactory.html) add-on, but I have no idea if my settings will export properly. When I transform the object using dimensions: xyz The object shrinks in size, but the bolt factory still has huge values. When I create a new bolt/screw type it's enormous compared to my ~6cm tall object.

I would like to have the setting permanent on every new file, since it's the only thing I would use Blender for.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Dimensions are usually interpreted by 3d printing software(slicers) as well, so you have to be careful to make sure they are correctly imported to whatever software the models go through before printing as well.

In Blender scene units are set in the Scene Properties tab in the Properties Editor:

[image]

Blender stores coordinate values in 32bit floats and the precision of numerical values in Blender as in all CG software(CAD software often uses more precise 64bit floats) is not infinite so for 3d printing it might make sense to change unit scale to millimeters so you can work with small values with no problems. Centimeters would work absolutely fine as well. You can see millimeters set up in the picture - unit scale set to 0.001 of the default unit that is 1m in Blender.

If you wish to always have the same settings when you open Blender, you should set them up in an empty scene and save it as default scene choosing File -> Defaults -> Save Startup File:

[image]

Note that other software likely will not recognise the units by default and you may have to set them correctly when you import your 3d models from Blender to it. How you do that depends on that software and you should refer to its documentation to find out how it works.